# Remove alternative data stream using powershell

Tags: powershell, alternate-data-stream

I'm trying to remove a bunch of OSX alternate data streams on an NTFS volume. However no matter what I try I cannot get Powershell to do it. Yes, I admit that my powershell is not great. Is anyone able to help?

**Objective:** Remove the ADS "AFP_AfpInfo" from any directory in the volume.

**Current Code:**

```
Get-ChildItem E:\ -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $streams = Get-Content -Path $_ -Stream AFP_AfpInfo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($streams) {
        $streams | ForEach-Object {
            try {
                Remove-Item -Path "$($_.PSPath)" -Stream AFP_AfpInfo -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Silentlycontinue
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current error:

```
An error occurred: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Stream'.
```

**Note:** Running Powershell 7.3

Answer (score 2):

`-Recurse` and `-Stream` don't seem to go together even though in the documentation they appear in the same [Parameter Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3#syntax). In this case `-Recurse` should be removed. [GitHub Issue #9822](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9822) was submitted to add clarification to the `Remove-Item` doc.

Also, you're seeking for an exact stream, `AFP_AfpInfo`, so I don't see a need to enumerate `$streams`. Lastly, checking if a file or folder has an alternative stream should be done with [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-remove-an-alternate-data-stream) instead of `Get-Content` for efficiency.

As a final aside, the code must use the [`.Remove` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.itemcmdletproviderintrinsics.remove?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-itemcmdletproviderintrinsics-remove(system-string()-system-boolean-system-boolean-system-boolean)) from [EngineIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.engineintrinsics?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) to work, `Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force` will **always** ask for confirmation on folders, *arguably a bug.* `Remove-Item` should skip confirmation checks if `-Stream` is in use and `-Confirm:$false -Force`. [GitHub issue #19154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19154) was submitted to follow up on this.

```
$removeFunc   = $ExecutionContext.InvokeProvider.Item.Remove
$targetStream = 'AFP_AfpInfo'

Get-ChildItem E:\ -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    if ($stream = $_ | Get-Item -Stream $targetStream -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        try {
            $removeFunc.Invoke($stream.PSPath, $false, $true, $true)
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobP yep, I'm seeing that. see my update, that should work

Comment: I had to switch on the literalpath flag to escape filenames correctly. It was skipping some. $removeFunc.Invoke($stream.PSPath, $false, $true, $true)

Comment: @RobP good call. I've update my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just using the `Unblock-File` cmdlet to remove ADS?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.3

> Description This cmdlet only works on the Windows and macOS platforms.
>
> The Unblock-File cmdlet lets you open files that were downloaded from
> the internet. It unblocks PowerShell script files that were downloaded
> from the internet so you can run them, even when the PowerShell
> execution policy is RemoteSigned. By default, these files are blocked
> to protect the computer from untrusted files.
>
> Before using the Unblock-File cmdlet, review the file and its source
> and verify that it is safe to open.
>
> Internally, the Unblock-File cmdlet ***removes the Zone.Identifier***
> ***alternate data stream***, which has a value of 3 to indicate that it was
> downloaded from the internet.

```
 Get-Help -Name Unblock-FIle -Examples

NAME
    Unblock-File
    
SYNOPSIS
    Unblocks files that were downloaded from the internet.
    
    
    ------------------ Example 1: Unblock a file ------------------
    
    PS C:\> Unblock-File -Path C:\Users\User01\Documents\Downloads\PowerShellTips.chm
    
    
    -------------- Example 2: Unblock multiple files --------------
    
    PS C:\> dir C:\Downloads\*PowerShell* | Unblock-File
    
    
    ------------- Example 3: Find and unblock scripts -------------
    
    PS C:\> Get-Item * -Stream "Zone.Identifier" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       FileName: C:\ps-test\Start-ActivityTracker.ps1
```

See also `Get-Item`, `Clear-Content` and `Remove-Item` cmdlets use case:

> Friday Fun with PowerShell and Alternate Data Streams
> https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/scripting/8888/friday-fun-with-powershell-and-alternate-data-streams

You could also just use the MSSysinternals tool to remove ADS as well in your PS code.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams