# How to search and replace combined with if & else in powershell

Tags: powershell, text, addition

Every night I got a text file that needs to be edited manually.
The file contains approximately 250 rows. Three example of a rows:

```
112;20-21;32;20-21;24;0;2;248;271;3;3;;
69;1;4;173390;5;0;0;5460;5464;3;3;;
24;7;4;173390;227;0;0;0;0;3;3;;
```

I need to replace the two last values in each row.
All rows ending with ;0;3;3;; should be replaced with ;0;17;18;; (the last one, solved)

The logic for the other two:
If the row contain a '-' it should replace the two last values from ;3;3;; to ;21;21;;
If it don´t have a '-' it should replace the two last values from ;3;3;; to ;22;22;;

This is my script

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.*)
{
  

(Get-Content $file) -replace ';0;3;3;;',';;0;17;18;;' -replace ';3;3;;',';21;21;;' |Out-file -encoding ASCII $file-new}
```

If I could add a '-' in the end of each row continga a '-' I could solve the issue with a modified script:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace ';0;3;3;;',';;0;17;18;;' -replace ';3;3;;-',';22;22;;' -replace ';3;3;;',';21;21;;'|Out-file -encoding ASCII $file-new}`
```

But how do I add a '-' in the end of a row, if the row contain a '-'?

Best Regards

Mr DXF

I tried with select-string, but I can´t figure it out...

```
if select-string -pattern '-' {append-text '-'|out-file -encoding ascii $file-new
else end
}
```

Comment: You could treat it as a csv with a ; delimiter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might do the trick, it uses a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-Regex` flag to read your files and match lines with regular expressions.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.* -File) {
    & {
        switch -Regex -File $file.FullName {
            # if the line ends with `;3;3;;` but is not preceded by `;0`
            '(?<!;0);3;3;;$' {
                # if it contains a `-`
                if($_.Contains('-')) {
                    $_ -replace ';3;3;;$', ';21;21;;'
                    continue
                }

                # if it doesn't contain a `-`
                $_ -replace ';3;3;;$', ';22;22;;'
                continue
            }
            # if the line ends with `';0;3;3;;`
            ';0;3;3;;$' {
                $_ -replace ';0;3;3;;$', ';0;17;18;;'
                continue
            }
            # if none of the above conditions are matched,
            # output as is
            Default { $_ }
        }
    } | Set-Content "$($file.BaseName)-new$($file.Extension)" -Encoding ascii
}
```

Using the content example in question the end result would become:

```
112;20-21;32;20-21;24;0;2;248;271;21;21;;
69;1;4;173390;5;0;0;5460;5464;22;22;;
24;7;4;173390;227;0;0;0;0;17;18;;
```

Comment: @mklement0 thank you, didnt even notice!

Comment: @mklement0 unrelated but do you think an issue should be raised for `Remove-Item` not skipping confirmation checks when `-Stream` is used on folders? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442886/remove-alternative-data-stream-using-powershell/75443083#75443083 EngineIntrinsics works fine as workaround but not all folks know how

Comment: I think so, yes. I think the fact that `-Stream` and `-Recurse` can be specified together without creating a syntax error should also be fixed (though I'm unclear on the specific nature of the fix; see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14701#issuecomment-773476552 for the parameter-binding order).

Comment: thanks @mklement0 will raise one later. autocompletion on the cmdlet is also misleading https://i.imgur.com/ntUuvLo.png understandable since its a dynamic param. Re. the syntax error, it does throw a ParameterBindingException when both are used.